# failed to copy stream when try to post form body files to api using httpclient

Tags: c#, .net-core

i'm trying  to post form data images and text from my website to api
but when i post  image with size 2kb it return error when copy the stream, other wise it work fine  using core 3.1  this issue appear only when deploy this with devops pipeline is that size issue?
when i post a small image it work

````
                HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
                MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                int count = 0;

                foreach (PostImage _Image in _Images)
                {
                    int altcout = 0;
                    byte[] data;
                    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(_Image.ImageFile.OpenReadStream()))
                    {
                        data = br.ReadBytes((int)_Image.ImageFile.OpenReadStream().Length);
                    }
                    ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);
                    Stream _strem = _Image.ImageFile.OpenReadStream();
                    multiContent.Add(bytes, $"images[{count}].ImageFile", _Image.ImageFile.FileName.Split("-").Last());
                    foreach (var alt in _Image.AltText)
                    {
                        multiContent.Add(new StringContent(alt.alttext), $"images[{count}].AltText[{altcout}].alttext");
                        multiContent.Add(new StringContent(alt.lang), $"images[{count}].AltText[{altcout}].lang");
                        altcout++;
                    }
                    multiContent.Add(new StringContent(_Image.IsOriginal), $"images[{count}].IsOriginal");
                    multiContent.Add(new StringContent(_Image.Subject_id.ToString()), $"images[{count}].Subject_id");
                    multiContent.Add(new StringContent(_Image.url), $"images[{count}].url");
                    if (_Image.OriginalImageId.HasValue)
                    {
                        multiContent.Add(new StringContent(_Image.OriginalImageId.ToString()), $"images[{count}].OriginalImageId");
                    }
                    count++;
                }

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add();
                messge = client.PostAsync($"{Url}/AddImage?UserEmail={Email}", multiContent).Result;
                _error.Satus = messge.StatusCode;

                _error.Message = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Before execution done of these methods, client timeouts the request. But small images' execution are much more faster that it seems like "working"

You should convert method as `async Task<T>` and `await Async()` methods such as `ReadAsStringAsync()`, `PostAsync()`.

Like,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MethodName(params if you have)
{
      .....
      .....
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     
      messge = await client.PostAsync($"{Url}/AddImage?UserEmail={Email}", multiContent).Result;
      _error.Satus = messge.StatusCode;

      _error.Message = await messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      return Ok();
}
```

Comment: no this not solve the issue it  return ```Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..```

Comment: How do you call this api method?